# Como reproduzir o efeito "overflow: hidden" do CSS em WPF?

Tags: wpf

Olá, sou novato com Windows Presentation Forms (WPF) e preciso saber como posso fazer o efeito de "overflow: hidden" que temos no CSS. Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
<Border BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="12">
    <Label Content="Foo" Background="Red"/>
</Border>
```

A intenção do código acima seria recriar o código abaixo

```
<label style="overflow:hidden; background:red; border-radius:12;">foo</label>
```

Como posso fazer com que o Border "oculte as sobras" do meu label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não conheço muito bem como funciona o "overflow:hidden;", CSS definitivamente não é minha praia. Pelo que eu pesquisei sobre ele, quando o conteúdo do texto for muito grande, ele vai cortar e esconder o texto, como [nesse](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow) link. Se for isso mesmo que você quer fazer, fiz uma simulação.

O objetivo final é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O primeiro passo é entender que o se não for definido a largura e altura máxima, o label e o border vão expandir para ocupar toda a área do container que eles estiverem, portando, esse código gera a imagem abaixo:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="12">
            <Label Background="Red" Content="Foo 1234561561f65d1s6f" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí tem duas situações, imagino que você tenha usado o CornerRadius="12" no border porque quer os cantos arredondados, certo? Se for, precisa mudar seu código para isso:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="Red" CornerRadius="12">
            <Label Content="Foo 1234561561f65d1s6f" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

E terá esse resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por último, para restringir o tamanho do label, basta inserir as propriedades Width e Height como no código abaixo:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="Red" Width="50" Height="30" CornerRadius="12">
            <Label Content="Foo 1234561561f65d1s6f" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

E o resultado final é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Um dica fora da sua pergunta:**

*Se você for usar o label apenas para apresentar texto, troca por TextBlock, por questões de desempenho mesmo.*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="Red" Width="50" Height="30" CornerRadius="12">
            <TextBlock Text="Foo 1234561561f65d1s6f" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter entendido sua pergunta, se não for isso, posta uma foto do resultado com css que eu vejo se consigo te ajudar.